# How to use external javascript libraries in NetSuite Suite Script 2.0?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I really hate the way netsuite suite script 2.0 handles date formatting.  So, I would like to use Moment.js for parsing dates that I get back from a web service call.  How do I get this to work inside a suite script 2.0?

As [erictgrubaugh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2387970/erictgrubaugh) stated, I needed to add the moment.js library to the NetSuite file cabinet and then in the debugger use the library.  Also note that my script is in  File Cabinet -> SuiteScripts -> Libraries

But even so, I was having problems with the syntax. Because when I use the debugger it now doesn't throw any errors, but I can't step through any of the code and a log statement doesn't print anything.

```
/** * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType ScheduledScript
 */

define ([
 'N/log',
 '../Libraries/moment',
 ],

function(log, moment) {





var a = moment('2016-01-01'); 
var b = a.clone().add(1, 'week'); 
log.debug(b);

});
```

Answer (score 6):

In general, the external library simply needs to be an [AMD-formatted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_module_definition) module, and you can include it directly in your code. If the library you want to use isn't AMD-compatible, there is extra work to do.

`moment` is AMD-compatible, so all you need to do is put the `moment` source file in your File Cabinet somewhere, then include it in your dependencies by its path.

```
require(["path/to/moment"], function (moment) {
    // use moment as usual
});
```

Here's a working example where I have `moment.min.js` in a sibling `lib` directory: https://gitlab.com/stoicsoftware/netsuite-sku-analytics/blob/master/FileCabinet/SuiteScripts/sku-analytics/total-monthly-by-sku/sa-TotalMonthlyBySku.js

Comment: Actually I don't think it works.  Because even though the debugger doesn't throw any errors, I can't step through the code.

Comment: I rarely use the debugger myself, but perhaps there will be others who can add input as well.

Comment: this works in a UE script. `define(['N/record', 'N/log', 'N/ui/serverWidget', './moment.min.js'], function(record,log,ui,moment){}` I'll echo Eric here. I find the debugger generally less than productive.

Comment: That's strange you needed the `.js` portion of the path; I've never seen that be necessary, though I know there are changes to the `require` library in 2017.1. Has your environment been updated @bknights?

Comment: Didn't try without it.

Answer (score 4):

You said:

> *Because when I use the debugger it now doesn't throw any errors, but I can't step through any of the code and a log statement doesn't print anything.*

But from the documentation:

> Note If you need to ad-hoc debug your code in the **NetSuite Debugger**, you must use a `require()` function. The **NetSuite Debugger** cannot step though a `define()` function.

Answer (score 0):

I can , in debugger:

```
require(["SuiteScripts/moment"], function (moment) {

var __d= moment().format(); 
var x =0; //breakpoint
});
```

[image]

this works